# WriteLine of program not displaying

Tags: vb.net, console, average

I am trying to create a program that takes the input of three numbers, averages them, and prints the average. 
The code I have so far:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Average As Double

    Console.WriteLine("Please input first number:")
    Dim Num1 As String
    Num1 = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Please input second number:")
    Dim Num2 As String
    Num1 = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Please input third number:")
    Dim Num3 As String
    Num3 = Console.ReadLine()

    Average = (Num1 + Num2 + Num3) / 3
    Console.WriteLine("Your average is: ", Average)
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

I enter three numbers, and then my program displays the text, "Your average is" But there's no value there; it's just blank after the text.

Comment: Should not you have `Num2 = Console.ReadLine()` instead of the second `Num1 = Console.ReadLine()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with string concatenation

```
Console.WriteLine("Your average is: " + Average.ToString)
```

Or using a composite format string

```
Console.WriteLine("Your average is: {0}", Average)
```

[See MSDN on Console.WriteLine(string, object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx)

**EDIT:** You need to convert that string input in a correct number before attempting to execute an addition and a division on them

```
Dim Num1 as Integer
While(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), Num1)
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter a integer number")

' and so on for the other inputs '
```

And, please, do a favor to yourself and set [`Option Strict On`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for your projects. These kind of automatic conversions are evil.

Comment: +1. I did not know `Console.WriteLine` had `String.Format` built in.

Comment: Thanks, got the program to return a value using the composite format string. Is there an issue with my math/logic though? I used `10` for all three numbers as a test, and it returned `33670` as my average.

Comment: @Matt: This is normal. It happens because you are concatenating strings, rather than actually adding up the numbers inside of them. `"10" + "10" + "10"` equals `"101010"`, when divided by 3, it becomes `33670`. You'd want to convert your num1,num2 and num3 to type Double, perhaps.

Comment: Yes, just noticed now that you use a string to accept numbers and then perform a concatenation operation on them ("10" + "10" + "10") gives back 101010 / 3

Comment: Much appreciated! Got the program working now great! Instead of using a string I went with integers with `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 1):

I think by this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your average is: ", Average)
```

You actually meant this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Your average is: {0}", Average))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input first number:")
Dim Num1 As String
Num1 = Console.ReadLine()

Console.WriteLine("Please input second number:")
Dim Num2 As String
Num1 = Console.ReadLine() ------ Use Num2 instead of Num1

Console.WriteLine("Please input third number:")
Dim Num3 As String
Num3 = Console.ReadLine()

Average = (Num1 + Num2 + Num3) / 3
Console.WriteLine("Your average is: ", Average) and use concat "&" here.
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit")
Console.ReadLine()
```